# Skip few fields validation from Schematics

Tags: python, validation, schema

Given a python schematics model, how can I get a new class with subset of fields (skipping few non-required fields).

For example -

```
from schematics.models import Model

class Category(Model):
    name = StringType(required=True, min_length=3, max_length=100)
    published = BooleanType(default=False)
    created = DateTimeType(required=True)
    updated = DateTimeType(required=True)
```

Here three fields are required, I want to validate with just name, ignoring `published`, `created` and `updated`